# Adding H2O2 in water does what to the pH of the water?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, water, ph

Not looking for numbers (unless required). I searched for this question on Google and found irrelevant results, with only the following link of some use but it doesn't appear to answer my question (unless I've misunderstood it).

https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_Chemical_interaction_occurs_when_hydrogen_peroxide_is_added_to_water

My previous understanding was that $\ce{H2O2}$ spontaneously dissociates into $\ce{H2O + O2}$, including in water. I had imagined this would have no effect on the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the water its added to.

The link above says if the water is acidic, $\ce{H2O2}$ will dissociate into hydronium + hydroperoxide ($\ce{H3O+ + HOO-}$). I imagine the production of hydronium will increase the $\mathrm{pH}$.

For example, if the water is slightly acidic, say $\mathrm{pH}$ $6.5$, will the addition of $\ce{H2O2}$ make the solution even more acidic?

Comment: How will production of more hydronium ions *increase* the pH?

Comment: (Rhetorical question) Is hydrogen peroxide a weak acid ?

Comment: @TRC I thought this is one indication of increasing acidity. That was a typo - I meant increasing acidity.

Comment: @Poutnik it is a weak acid but I am not certain if what I read in the link is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The $\mathrm p K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{H2O2}$ is $11.75$ in Wikipedia.  As a consequence, adding enough $\ce{H2O2}$ to make it concentration  $\ce{[H2O2]}$ go up to $\pu{1M}$ with change the original pH $6.5$ to $6.0$

Comment: Ok I can understand the pKa, but if all of H2O2 is disassociating into H2O and O2, why is the pH dropping?

Comment: Ordinary water in contact with air has a pH 5.5 ± 0.3, depending upon the quality of the air. This is due to some atmospheric  $\ce{CO2}$ that gets slowly dissolved into water. If your water had a pH equal to $6.5$, it means that it was kept out of contact with air. If it goes down to $5.5$ during decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$, it may be due to some dissolution of $\ce{CO2}$ and it may have nothing to do with $\ce{H2O2}$.